# Nested optimization problem

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I would like to solve a maximization problem which itself depends on a maximization.
I came up with this code,

```
pR[w_] := 
 Simplify[ ArgMax[{-p^2 + p w , p > 0, w > 0}, {p}] , w > 0] 
pR1[w_] := Part[pR[w], 1]
p2 = ArgMax[{ w - pR1[w]^2, 0 < w < 100}, {w}],
```

which works for analytically solveable functions.
However, the functions in my real problem are not analytically sovelable, such that I tried something like

```
pR[w_] := 
 Simplify[NArgMax[{-p^2 + p w , p > 0, w > 0}, {p}, 
   Method -> "DifferentialEvolution"], w > 0]
pR1[w_] := Part[pR[w], 1]
p2[i_] = NMaximize[{ w - pR1[w], 0 < w < 100}, {w}, 
  Method -> "DifferentialEvolution"],
```

which does not return any results.

Do you have any idea how I get my code to work for only! numerically solutions, that is, how does the bottom code has to look like?

Thank you in advance
Paul

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your second part `NMaximize` needs a functional with numerical arguments.

Try

```
pR[w_] := NArgMax[{-p^2 + p w, p > 0 }, p]  

J[w_?NumericQ] := w - pR[w]
NMaximize[{J[w], 0 <= w <= 100}, w  , Method -> "RandomSearch" ] 
(*{50., {w -> 100.}}*)
```

Don't know why the evaluation time is so long.

remark: Mathematica knows to [solve minmax-problems](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ConstrainedOptimizationLocalNumerical.html#1422430628)

Comment: Thx, this was a good step into the right direction.